# 400 error message when trying to copy cells with vba

Tags: excel, vba

When I run my code I get a "400" error message. but it is only the last part of my code that doesn't work("creating template"). Im trying to copy cells A1:BA1000 from the sheet "Data" to a new sheet which is named based on the value of cell EU12 in the data sheet.

```
'copy the last values from december
Range("HI5:IA1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("IC5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'copy the date to new workbook.
Range("EU8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("EU12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'copy sheet to new workbook
sheettocopy = Range("EU10").Value
Worksheets(sheettocopy).Copy

'adding sheet and renaming
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Data").Range("EU12").Value


'creating template
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1:BA1000").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets("Data").Range("EU12").Value).Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

EDIT:

made a new macro just for the creation of a template, the code works(when stored in a module) but when i copy my first sheet in the beginning the module doesnt follow:

```
Sub addinfo()
'creating template
Set wk = ThisWorkbook
Dim template As String

template = Sheets("Data").Range("EU12").Value

wk.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:BA1000").Copy wk.Sheets(template).Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: try not to use '.Select' if it is possible, instead of that try
dim wk as workbook
set wk = thisworkbook
wk.sheets("Data").Range("A1:BA1000").Copy wk.Sheets(name).range("A1")
in every case of copy pasting

Comment: Hi thank you! I made some test in a new file and I think I got most of it. But you typed: "wk.sheets(name)...." 
I dont know the name of the sheet, tha name is specified as a string in a cell. 
How do I "point" to the correct sheet?

Comment: In the place of 'name' put name of sheet where You want to paste your data which You try to copy or variable to which You set a cell value.. with name of sheet :)

Comment: how do I do that? 
I tried:
Set wk = ThisWorkbook
sheettocopy = Range("B2").Value

wk.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:A20").Copy wk.Sheets(sheettocopy).Range("A1")

Comment: sheettocopy = wk.sheets(NameOfSheetWhereB2Cell).Range("B2").Value
and only if You declared dim sheettocopy as string ofc.

Comment: it worked in my test file, but when implementing it in my original file I get "subscript out of range" error

Comment: So now put your original code in post (edit your post). I will take a look :)

Comment: when I copy the sheet with the macros unto a new workbook, the macros follow, but they "point" to the macro from the old sheet, that is why I get the subscript error. It's solved by assigning a new macro(so it points to the active doc instead of old). even though it is the same code in both macros. any idea how to solve it a better way?

Comment: I don't know what do You mean by saying "point to the macro"